# How to do Interpolation Search from Strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

Interpolation Search is a modification of Binary Search where in binary search the input is divided into two equal halves in each iteration by computing. You can do interpolation search on integers as below.

```
public static int interpolationSearch(int[] sortedArray, int toFind) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = sortedArray.length - 1;
    int mid;
    while (sortedArray[low] <= toFind && sortedArray[high] >= toFind) {
        if (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low] == 0)
            return (low + high) / 2;
        // out of range is possible here
        mid = low + ((toFind - sortedArray[low]) * (high - low)) / (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low]);

        if (sortedArray[mid] < toFind)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (sortedArray[mid] > toFind)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    if (sortedArray[low] == toFind)
        return low;
    // not found
    else
        return -1;
}
```

But when it comes to strings above algorithm cannot be used directly. Here most of the comparisons can be replaced by java **compareTo** method. But what would be the best way to carry out below operation for strings?

```
mid = low + ((toFind - sortedArray[low]) * (high - low)) / (sortedArray[high] - sortedArray[low]);
```

Comment: What you  expect from the result of multiplying, dividing and subtracting strings?

Comment: This seems similar to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3661629/interpolation-search-on-strings

Comment: BTW, Google gives many more results for interpolation search on Strings. You might want to research a bit.

Comment: Already did the research. But did not find the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proportional interpolation of strings makes sense if you think of them as base-K fractions, where K is the number of characters in the alphabet and the implicit radix point is in front of the string. For example,

```
.aaa < .aaaa < .aaaaa
```

just as

```
.111 < .1111 < .11111
```

With this interpretation, we can use normal numerical interpolation of, say, `x` and `y` with parameter `T`, in any of the usual forms.

```
I(T) = T * x + (1 - T) * y = y + T * (x - y)
```

For interpolation search, we know I(T). It's the string we're searching for written as a radix-K fraction. And we want to find T * D, where D is the size of the current search "gap".  With some simple algebra we get:

```
T * D = D * (I(T) - y) / (x - y)
```

Where again `x` and `y` are the radix-K fractions, the interpolated strings.

The trick is implementing this arithmetic in a reasonably efficient manner.  A nice thing about this formula is that we can scale `x`, `y`, and `I(T)` by the same factor, and it still holds. Consequently, we can scale them into `BigInteger`s as long as the longest of the three strings, assuming characters collate as unsigned bytes. Hence K=256. Then the division just truncates to get the desired index. Here's a quick hack. It may contain bugs, but the idea is correct.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import static java.math.BigInteger.ZERO;
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII;
import static java.util.Arrays.copyOf;
import static java.lang.Math.max;

public class InterpolationSearch {
  static int interpolate(String ys, String xs, String iOfTs, int id) {
    int maxLen = max(max(xs.length(), ys.length()), iOfTs.length());
    BigInteger x = new BigInteger(1, copyOf(xs.getBytes(US_ASCII), maxLen));
    BigInteger y = new BigInteger(1, copyOf(ys.getBytes(US_ASCII), maxLen));
    BigInteger iOfT = new BigInteger(1, copyOf(iOfTs.getBytes(US_ASCII), maxLen));
    BigInteger d = BigInteger.valueOf(id);
    BigInteger den = x.subtract(y);
    return ZERO.equals(den) ? 0 : (int) d.multiply(iOfT.subtract(y)).divide(den).longValue();
  }

  static int search(String [] a, String target) {
    int p = 0;
    int q = a.length - 1;
    while (target.compareTo(a[p]) >= 0 && target.compareTo(a[q]) <= 0) {
      int m = p + interpolate(a[p], a[q], target, q - p);
      int cmp = target.compareTo(a[m]);
      if (cmp < 0) q = m - 1;
      else if (cmp > 0) p = m + 1;
      else return m;
    }
    return -1; // search fail
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    String [] data = {
      "bbbb",
      "cccccccc",
      "ddd",
      "eeeeeee",
      "fffff",
      "ggggggggggggggg",
      "hhhhh",
    };   
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
      System.out.println(search(data, data[i]));
    }
    System.out.println(search(data, "bbb"));
    System.out.println(search(data, "hhhhhh"));
    System.out.println(search(data, "eeeee"));
  }
}
```

As you'd hope and expect, the searches for the values in the data array take one iteration each except a single case that needs two.

**Additional note**

I want to point out that the code above is interesting, and it works, but simple interpolation using the Latin-1 character code gives bad performance when used on real world collections strings. This is because big chunks of the 256 possible character values contain few or no characters. E.g. a missing character is encoded as a 0 above, but there are unlikely to be any strings at all with codes between 0 and 64. It's worse if all words are lower case, since that extends the empty range up to 95. The mostly unused codes skew the interpolated value. To avoid this, convert to radix-K fractions where K is the number of characters actually used in the strings, and those characters are mapped into values 0 to K-1.

Even so, you'll only get good results if all the characters occur with roughly equal frequency and random placement. Real strings often lack these properties.

All this is to explain why interpolation search is seldom used in practice.  Real data sets can be remarkably non-random.

Comment: `int cmp = target.compareTo(a[m]);` will lead to a array index out of bound exception

Comment: @TharinduKumara I've run the code. It doesn't. Under what conditions?  `interpolate` always returns a value in 0..q-p, so adding p gives a value in p..q, which is always in the array.

Comment: I tested with this values, but it returned -1 most of the time. `"Azevedo, Ana", "Silva, Rui", "Boussebough, Imane", "Terracina, Giorgio,",  "Lefebvre, Peter", "Houghten, Sher", "Revesz, Peter"`

Comment: @TharinduKumara Your data isn't sorted. Interpolation sort requires that. When I sort the data properly, it works fine.

Comment: @TharinduKumara Try this order: "Azevedo, Ana", 
      "Boussebough, Imane", 
      "Houghten, Sher", 
      "Lefebvre, Peter", 
      "Revesz, Peter",
      "Silva, Rui", 
      "Terracina, Giorgio,",

Comment: I am testing this with an array of 2000 string. But there it gives a array index out bound exception. https://codeshare.io/5gAQER

Comment: This is the dataset(https://codeshare.io/5gAQER), I am using and I am trying to search these values `"Azevedo, Ana", "Silva, Rui", "Boussebough, Imane", "Terracina, Giorgio,", "Lefebvre, Peter", "Houghten, Sher", "Revesz, Peter"` @Gene

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for a metric that will help you create a proper distance of the strings regarding their lexicographical order. Hamming and Levenshtein won't work. I suggest this one:

```
int[] dist = new int[] { a[0]-b[0], a[1]-b[1], ..., a[max]-b[max] };
```

where `max` is the maximum length of the two strings `a` and `b`, and `a[i]` (`b[i]`) is 0 for any `i` out of range of that string. Effectively, `dist` is an n-tuple of distances where the first letters of the compared strings shall get the highest significance.

Performance-wise it looks painful to compute, but it's a try.

```
import java.lang.math.BigDecimal;

static BigDecimal dist(String s1, String s2) {
    int maxlen = Math.max(s1.length(), s2.length());
    BigDecimal d = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxlen; i++) {
        int dist;
        if (i < s1.length() && i < s2.length()) {
            dist = s1.charAt(i) - s2.charAt(i);
        } else if (i < s1.length()) {
            dist = s1.charAt(i);
        } else {
            dist = -s2.charAt(i);
        }
        d = d.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(dist * Math.pow(2, -i * 8)));
    }
    return d;
}
```

Comment: How we can apply this to Interpolation Search?

Comment: my requirement is to provide a string array `public static int interpolationSearch(string[] sortedArray, string toFind)`

Comment: what would be the return value of dist function? @yacc

Comment: A fixed point value, like `d0.d1d2d3d4d5....` where `d0` is equal to `a[0]-b[0]`. Or likewise, a byte stream `d0d1d2d3...dmax` if you know there's a maximum length of your strings. @TharinduKumara

Comment: `static int dist(String s1, String s2) {
        String longStr= s1;
        String  shortStr = s2;

        if(s1.length() < s2.length()) {
            longString = s2;
            shortString = s1;
        }

        int dist [] = new int[longString.length()];

        for(int i =0; i < longStr.length(); i++ ) {
            if(i < shortStr.length())
                dist[i] = longStr.charAt(i) - shortStr.charAt(i);
            else
                dist[i] = 1;
        }

        int d = 1;

        for(int i: dist) 
            d *= i;
        
        return d;
    }`

Comment: is this what you meant @yacc?

Answer (score 1):

You can very well see the strings as base-26 numbers (assuming case insensitivity), so that interpolation makes sense. You can convert to integer, interpolate and then back to base-26, or implement the four operations on the base-26 representation.

Anyway, chances are lower that the distribution of the keys is as regular as it can be for numbers, so that interpolation search might be counter-productive.

Comment: If I had words like 'be' and 'bee', say, how would that make them more distant from 'at'? Given the base-26 translation, 'at' would be closer to 'be' than 'bee'.

Comment: @yacc: make all words the same length by appending a's (or a reserved character acting as a 0). You can make this virtually.

Comment: So that all character positions get the right ordinal with respect to their peers, agreed. What about 'rate: a' and 'rate: aaa'? That would make them equal.